# how to bind value of v-for to v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with BootstrapVue. To my problem: I have a `v-for` in my template in which I have two `buttons`.

Looping over my `v-for` my `v-if` doesn't generate unique `IDs` and than after clicking one button each button will be triggered *(from `Open me!` to `Close me!` and other way around)*.

How can I manage to get each button only triggers itself and doesn't affect the other?

I think I have to use my `n` of my `v-for` but I actually don't know how to bind this to a `v-if`..

Thanks in advance!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="n in inputs" :key="n.id">
      <b-button v-if="hide" @click="open()">Open me!</b-button>
      <b-button v-if="!hide" @click="close()">Close me! </b-button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <b-button @click="addInput">Add Input</b-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      id: null,
      inputs: [{
        id: 0
      }],
      hide: true,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    open() {
      this.hide = false
    },

    close() {
      this.hide = true
    },

    addInput() {
      this.inputs.push({
        id: this.id += 1;
      })
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I would recommend to save the hidden items by index in an array.

Comment: You shouldn't loop of plain numbers, but over an array that contains a list of booleans or objects, the reflect the state of your buttons.

Comment: just for your info. In my real code I looping over ```v-for``` from a json and I have unique IDs so ```v-for="(array, index) in json"``` and for this ```array``` I'm generating unique IDs! But I after looping over it my ```v-if``` will be triggerd for each button..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything seems to look fine. In order to handle each button triggers,
you can maintain an object like so:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{id: 0, visible: false}],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    open(index) {
      this.inputs[index].visible = false
    },

    close(index) {
      this.inputs[index].visible = true
    },
    addInput() {
      this.inputs.push({id: this.inputs.length, visible: false});
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

and your template should be like

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(val, index) in inputs" :key="val.id">
      <b-button v-if="val.visible" @click="open(index)">Open me!</b-button>
      <b-button v-if="!val.visible" @click="close(index)">Close me! </b-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Edit:

You don't need to insert an id every time you create a row, instead can use the key as id. Note that the `inputs` is an object and not array so that even if you want to delete a row, you can just pass the index and get it removed.

Comment: Hi, edited my question. I think it was stupid to show it with a ```number``` for value of my ```v-for```. Your answer is exactly what I need - but I need this for manual ```inputs``` after a click event. As you can see in my updated question! Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: Hi, I have to create a unique ID every time, because of my future code. But actually this answer is not what I need. Please notice that I'm pushing with an extra button ```inputs``` each time.. could you please update your answer based on my code? keyy is like index and this is not unique.. the easiest way for me is if I'm able to bind my v-if with ```n.id```..

Comment: Based on your request, I have made the edit...pls check

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array of objects. Use a boolean as property to show or hide the clicked item.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    buttons: []
  },
  created () {
    this.createButtons()
    this.addPropertyToButtons()
  },
  methods: {
 
  createButtons() {
    // Let's just create buttons with an id
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.buttons.push({id: i})
    }
  },
  
  addPropertyToButtons() {
   // This method add a new property to buttons AFTER its generated
   this.buttons.forEach(button => button.show = true)
  },
  
  toggleButton(button) {
   if (button.show) {
    button.show = false
  } else {
    button.show = true
  }
  // We are changing the object after it's been loaded, so we need to update ourselves
  app.$forceUpdate();
  }
  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="button in buttons" :key="button.id">
      <button v-if="button.show" @click="toggleButton(button)">Open me!</button>
      <button v-if="!button.show" @click="toggleButton(button)">Close me! </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me out. I think I underrated the output of my input. I've updated my question.. I'm not actually looping over a ```number```.. I'm looping over manually generated inputs with a unique ```id```.. sorry for the missunderstanding!

Comment: Can you add a property 'show' to your generated inputs? Maybe in the generation process? Anyhow, the principle stays the same :) EDIT: I looked at your edit, it's definitly possible! ;)

Comment: I've tried this.. but actually all I'm doing I get errros over errors..

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to make an edit with your updated code :)

Comment: Hey Patrick, I made a simple change and added some comments. If you still have an error, please post this as well :)