# Toggle data in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to display data for each record by language(so more languages will be there, there will be more tabs for each record),

So I made a simple method, if the value equals key and index it should display the required tab.

I have following markup in template:

```
        <div
          class="nav-item"
          v-for="(property, keyProp) in item.props"
          :key="keyProp"
        >
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-line-tabs mb-5 fs-6">
            <li class="nav-item" v-for="(language, key) in property" :key="key">
              <a
                class="nav-link"
                data-bs-toggle="tab"
                @click="toggle(key + keyProp)"
              >
                {{ key }}
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div
            v-for="(language, key) in property"
            :key="key"
            v-show="isOpenIndex === key + keyProp"
          >
            {{ key + keyProp }}
            <input
              type="text"
              v-model="language.text"
              class="form-control form-control-solid"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
```

And method:

```
  methods: {
    toggle: function (index) {
      this.isOpenIndex = index;
    },
```

But for some reason it doesn't work in this way. I can make it work like if I add to `data` something like `isOpenIndex: this.IsOpenIndex` but it will display only one tab in a time, closing others if I press another. How to prevent that?

I only want to close the previously opened tab if it's the same record only.

Comment: isOpenIndex will change when you close or choose another. It will always be one value, how do you expect to have multiple open at once?

Comment: Hm, true. But what if to store all pressed tabs in array? That gives question, how to search in array when doing for required pattern in ```v-show```?

Comment: I would add this to the object itself. By coincidence I answered the same answer a few days ago. Look at this answer and say if this helps you further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807074/how-to-bind-value-of-v-for-to-v-if/69807298#69807298

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem, solved now!

Answer (score 0):

So I come up with this, slightly modified method function and everything works.

```
    toggle: function (id, lang, type) {
      for(var key in this.item.props[id][lang]) {
         var prop = this.item.props[id][lang][key];
         if(prop.active === true) {
           return [ prop.active = false, this.item.props[id][lang][type].active = true ]
         }
      }
      return this.item.props[id][lang][type].active = true   
    },
```

I've added to each value `active: false`, so by default all hidden. Though when method gets run, it replaces `false` to `true`, if `true` already set it goes though `if` statement inside loop and drop old parameter to `false` and replace new one with `true`